# No reverse match with data that has / in it

Tags: python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

I have a system that contains student ids. When I save an id with a **/** in it, the system returns no reverse match error but works with ids without the slash. What could be the problem?
My url

```
path('borrowed/<borrowed>',views.all_borrowed,name='all_borrowed'),
```

The error

```
Reverse for 'all_borrowed' with arguments '('557/2019',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['library/borrowed/(?P<borrowed>[^/]+)$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`<str:…>`** path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) does not accept a slash in the parameter, you can work with the [**`<path:…>`** path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('borrowed/<path:borrowed>/',views.all_borrowed,name='all_borrowed'),
```